# Can't get the relative path right React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path

Folder structure:

```
 my-app/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  src/
    websites/Home.js
    pictures/Group140.png
    App.js
    index.js
```

I am located in Home.js
I am trying to `import Logo from "../pictures/Group140.png";` 
and use it as a `src={Logo}` on img. Keep getting this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../pictures/Group140.png' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Website\my-app\src\websites'
```

[image]

Comment: Also vs code shows the pictures folder but not images in the folder when typing the path

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the folder structure? Your relative path should work. Also, images are not showing in vscode by default, it's ok to write it manually.

Comment: @NicolasHevia Just added the screenshot the pictures folder does contain Group140.png

Comment: are you using `react-create-app`? if so you should store the img in public folder and access them like [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder). Otherwise you will have to [import the image](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files).

Comment: Thank you this worked

Answer (score 0):

In `react-create-app` you have to [import the image](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) if you want to use it in your javascript code, you can see that in the default `app.js` file where it imports the logo.

Alternatively you can put your images (or other assets) inside the `public` folder and access them directly. RCA already saved the public folder path in the handy env var `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.
See [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).